Why standardized LDPC codes, such 3GPP NR, have 4 cycles in Tanner Graph?
We know that short cycles in Tanner Graph are detrimental in error performance. So, Why standardized 5G NR LDPC codes have 4-cycles?
3rd generation Partnership Project (3GPP) had announced Base Matrix 1 and 2. I lifted them properly. I realized there are 4 cycles.
What are main reasons to keep 4 cycles, even though they are detrimental in error rate?
I was asked to clarify the question more. In Coding Theory, like in LDPC parity check matrices, short cycles are avoided. Because Short Cycles are bad for error correcting capability. Given this, in practice, standardized channel codes have 4 cycles. For example, 5G New Radio ldpc codes, released by 3GPP, has many 4 cycles. Why is it so? What are the benefits of keeping 4 cycles, even though we know short cycles are bad for error correcting capability? Why standard LDPC codes, used in 5G communication, have short cycles in their parity matrices?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should clarify (a link?) to which specific code you are dealing with. Which are the sizes of the matrix H, row/column weight ?

Anyway, it's known that 4-cycles are difficult to avoid in practice.

Please add a description of (or a link to) those codes. I lost contact with 3GPP fifteen years ago, and don't remember whether it is paywalled or not :-)

Anyway, rest assured, for a FEC code to be included into a standard, it must have passed extensive simulations by participating players. With flying colors. May be the relative weaknesses don't show at the targeted QoS? The only contact with LDPC codes I had back in the day was with digital broadcast (so TV). One LDPC code was then booted out, not because of 4-cycles but due to relatively small trapping sets. Then again, in that application we absolutely needed the error floor out (compressed video does not degrade gracefully). May be 5G only needs a well placed waterfall?

And, in case it was not obvious, I'm not an expert on LDPC codes :-)

Not an expert on coding, but note that performance alone is not the only factor that drives 3GPP design. There are the equally (if not more) important aspects of implementation complexity and flexibility (e.g., being able to easily generate multiple coding rates, applicable to multiple codeword lengths (transport block size)). I can only assume that the chosen LDPC design was deemed to provide the best compromise/trade-off among all these factors

Seconding the point @Stelios raised. An application needs to be able to flexibly support codes of variable information rates. A solution (in the case I'm familiar with) is that the LDPC codes must be constrained to come from a simple family. May be built around a particular circuitry enabling the belief propagation algorithm to work - you cannot easily route the messages required by a random Tanner graph). In other words, complexity of user equipment is a limiting factor.
